# Disable selection in a PrimeFaces data table but show previously selected value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to disable the selection in a PrimeFaces v8.0 data table, but show the previously selected value.

This is my minimal example project

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
  xml:lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
  <title>Disable table selection</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
  <h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
      <p:dataTable var="value"
                   value="#{disabledTableSelectionBean.values}"
                   selection="#{disabledTableSelectionBean.selectedValue}"
                   disabledSelection="true"
                   rowKey="#{value}">

        <p:column selectionMode="single" width="15" />

        <p:column headerText="Value">
          <h:outputText value="#{value}" />
        </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGrid>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Getter
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class DisabledTableSelectionBean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> values;

    private String selectedValue = "6";

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        values = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
    }

}
```

The displayed table looks like this

[Disabled selection in PrimeFaces data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABRf0.jpg)

What I want is, that the radio buttons are disabled, but to show the selected value "6", I selected in the backend bean.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine with Primefaces 6.2, with 8.0 you can try with this code:

```
    <p:dataTable var="value" value="#{disabledTableSelectionBean.values}"
        selection="#{disabledTableSelectionBean.selectedValue}"
        rowKey="#{value}">

        <p:column selectionMode="single" width="15"
            styleClass="ui-state-disabled" />

        <p:column headerText="Value">
            <h:outputText value="#{value}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Basically you remove the disable selection and add the style class directly on the radio column.

Comment: I did update my application from v6.2 to v8.0. Thank you very much. That solved the problem.

Comment: Doesn't applying a style only makes it look disabled? I think some JavaScript patching is required as well.

Comment: In theory I agree, but trying it I cannot change the selected by clicking on row or on other radio button, so it seems enough for that behavior.